# How to delete push key data from Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can I know on how to delete data under UserID push key? Currently, I'm using firebase and I need to delete specific booking data under UserID. For example, I want to delete the whole MOjF8qthpvBGrbZMtBS data, but once I click on delete button, all of the data is deleted as well. Please help ;')

[image]

```
public class BookingAdapterRecyclerView  extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<BookingAdapterRecyclerView.MyViewHolder>{
private List<Booking>bookingList;
private Activity mActivity;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public LinearLayout rl_layout;
    public TextView 
    tvname,tvphone,tvhouse,tvdate,tvtime,tvstatus,tvremarks;
    public RadioGroup radioGroup;
    public Button bDelete, bVerify;

    public MyViewHolder (View view){
        super(view);
        rl_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_layout);


        tvname = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvphone = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        tvhouse = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_house);
        tvdate = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        tvtime = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        tvstatus = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        tvremarks = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_remarks);
        bDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_item);
        bVerify = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_verify);
    }
}

public BookingAdapterRecyclerView(List<Booking>bookingList,Activity 
activity){
    this.bookingList = bookingList;
    this.mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.bookinglist_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Booking book = bookingList.get(position);

    holder.tvname.setText("Name :" + book.getName());
    holder.tvphone.setText("Phone Number :"+book.getPhone());
    holder.tvhouse.setText("House Address :"+book.getHouse());
    holder.tvdate.setText("Date Booking :"+book.getbDate());
    holder.tvtime.setText("Time Booking"+book.getbTime());
```

This is my delete function

```
    holder.bDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Booking")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot 
dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : 
dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    book.getKey();
                                    userSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                            }
                        }

                    });
        }
    });}

}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: You have to provide more details to code about booking date or something like this

Comment: provide firebase tree structure to understand the actual problem

Comment: The above code look like a recyclerview code. Please post activity code i provide changes for this might help you get key of childs

Comment: I am asking for activity code not recyclerview code cause we need to get id of childs also

Comment: do you have access to the userid?

Comment: yes i have the access to the userId @Peter

Comment: check my answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Booking").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               for(DataSnapshot subSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  subSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
             }
         }
        });
        }
    });}

}
```

If you don't have access to the `userId`, then you need to iterate twice and then using `getRef().removeValue()` you will be able to delete the random id with the data under it.

---

If you have access to the `userid`, then just do:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Booking").child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

`getCurrentUser()` returns the currently logged in user.

You need to reference the `userId` and then just loop once and it will get delete the data under `userId`.

Comment: sir, what if the admin side want to delete the data? is it still the same way? I try this on user side. it works.. but when i used it on admin side to delete the booking data.. it does not work.

Comment: if on admin side, then the admin is the currently login user. You need to have access to the user id. If you dont have access to that then you have to loop twice as i showed in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will remove every record as there is no if condition present to remove particular record, In order to remove that specific record inside for loop

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) // userSnapshot contains userId
     {          
          if (userSnapshot == userId) // check userId credential
          {
               for (DataSnapshot bookSnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) // it will fetch every book record in db
               {  
                    if(bookSnapshot.getChildren() == "MOjF8qthpvBGrbZMtBS")
                    {
                         userSnapshot.getChildren().removeValue();
                    }
                }
          }   
     }
}
```

Not sure about the syntax but logic is here